# impossible folder sharing by virt-viewer in Windows client

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm testing folder sharing using the virt viewer.

The guest OS is Windows. And I'm going to run a virt viewer on the Linux client and Windows client to see if folder sharing is possible.

I checked 'share folder' in the 'preference' section of the 'file' tab in the virt viewer.

First of all, I confirmed that the Linux client is possible doing folder sharing.
However, I confirmed that I could not check this 'share folder' button in the virt viewer running on the Windows client.

What did I forget?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

- open virtual machine details
- click Add Hardware
- select Channel
- select Name: org.spice-space.webdav.0
- click Finish
- (re)start vitrual machine

On the client

- install https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-webdavd/
- install https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe

Then change the prefs and select the folder.